# Error using angular component declared in a library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I created an angular workspace with some common components and a 2 angular app, but when i try to use it inside an angular application it gave me this error:

> "error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could
> not be resolved to an NgModule class."

here is the app.module.ts:

```
import { FormControlComponent } from 'my-library';
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormControlComponent,
  ],
```

my library has this code:

my-library.module.ts

```
declarations: [
  ...
  FormControlComponent,
  ...
],

exports: [
  ...
  FormControlComponent,
  ...
],
```

my public-api.ts has this code:

```
export * from './lib/form-control/form-control.component';
```

i builded the library and added to package.json:

"my-library": "file:dist/my-library",

Comment: you should put `MyLibraryModule` in imports section of your app.module, not the component

Comment: @Andrei ok, done, nothing change...

Comment: did you remove the component from imports section?

Comment: ah, ok, just the MyLibraryModule! yes it works now!